# getting previous value before edition from textbox in gridview

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, gridview

I am applying edit functionality on gridview.

When my code's control is in rowupdating event, i am finding that i am getting previous value from textbox(i.e. value before i make edit in textbox).

Following is my code:

```
Protected Sub gvBooking_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles gvBooking.RowUpdating
            'Dim name As String = DirectCast(gvBooking.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("txtperson1"), TextBox).Text
            Dim nname As String = (gvBooking.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Values("person_name").ToString)
            Dim id As Integer = Integer.Parse(gvBooking.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value.ToString)
            Dim carname As String = gvBooking.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Values("car_name").ToString

            Dim carac As String = ""


            'Dim sql As String = ""
            'sql = "update dbo.tbl_Book set person_name='" + name + "',ac_type='" + carac + "' where booking_id = " + id.ToString
            'gc.ExecuteCommand(sql)
            'gvBooking.EditIndex = -1
            'gc.BindGridView(gvBooking, "select * from tbl_Book")
        End Sub
```

In this, if i edit person name from Henry to Scott and then press update button, then i finds through debugger that nname is having the value Henry only, which is the value before i make edit, instead it should have value Scott which i edited.

I am not understanding where i am making mistake.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After clicking Update, two events will be raised.

1.) GridView.Updating : Raised just before the Update is about to be committed. 
    In this event the data is still not updated in the Database. Basically this event is meant for some dynamic changes to be applied if required before the Update method actually commits the changed data to database.

2.) GridView.Updated
    This event is raised immediately after data is updated. So it is in this event only that you put a debug symbol and check the Value. You will see your new value: Scott.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowUpdated="GridView1_RowUpdated"></asp:GridView>
```

As you are checking the data when update is not made.That's why you are getting the original values only. Inside the GridView1_RowUpdated() method only  check for the new values.

Also, still if you want to check your new values in Updating Event, Use GridViewUpdateEventArgs.NewValues [Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues.aspx) [ e.Newvalues ] as : [ Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues.aspx) here ]

```
  string s = e.NewValues[1].ToString(); // 2nd Column // c# sample
```

Comment: but all of my coligues has used updating event and its working fine with them,, i am not understanding what can be issue with it

Comment: Please make sure you have set the Updated event in your Markup portion. See above. Also edited my answer (Last 3 lines) to check new values in Updating event itself.